# I need to filter elements in google.visualization.datatable used in Google Charts

Tags: datatable, google-visualization

I'm populating my google's datatable via using this code

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Default2.aspx/GetChartData",
    data: "",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; chartset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        chartData = data.d;
    },
    error: function () {
    alert("Error loading data! Please try again.");
    }
}).done(function () {
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    });
function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);
```

Now I want to delete rows based on some filters which check the particular value(date) from the row of the datatable.
But the problem is that there is not any method in documentation using which i can go through row elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use a [DataView](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView) to show only certain rows from the DataTable

using the [`getFilteredRows`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_getFilteredRows)  and `setRows` methods...

the `getFilteredRows` method returns an array of row indexes that meet certain criteria

the criteria is an array of conditions

you pass the column index and the condition

e.g. --> `{column: 0, minValue: 2016}` -- (first column must be >= 2016)
e.g. --> `{column: 0, value: 2017}` -- (first column must = 2017)
e.g. --> `{column: 0, maxValue: 2015}` -- (first column must be <= 2015)

see following DataTable...

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['X', 'Y1', 'Y2'],
  [2010, 10, 14],
  [2011, 14, 22],
  [2012, 16, 24],
  [2013, 22, 30],
  [2014, 28, 36],
  [2015, 30, 44],
  [2016, 34, 42],
  [2017, 36, 44],
  [2018, 42, 50],
  [2019, 48, 56]
]);
```

to filter on the `'X'` column (column 0), we could say...

`data.getFilteredRows([{column: 0, minValue: 2016}])`

you can use multiple criteria as well...

```
data.getFilteredRows([
  {column: 0, minValue: 2016},
  {column: 1, minValue: 40}
])`
```

then pass the returned row indexes to `setRows` on the data view

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setRows(data.getFilteredRows([
  {column: 0, minValue: 2016},
  {column: 1, minValue: 40}
]));
```

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['table']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['X', 'Y1', 'Y2'],
    [2010, 10, 14],
    [2011, 14, 22],
    [2012, 16, 24],
    [2013, 22, 30],
    [2014, 28, 36],
    [2015, 30, 44],
    [2016, 34, 42],
    [2017, 36, 44],
    [2018, 42, 50],
    [2019, 48, 56]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setRows(data.getFilteredRows([
    {column: 0, minValue: 2016},
    {column: 1, minValue: 40}
  ]));

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Table(container);
  chart.draw(view);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

**EDIT**

you can filter on any type, including dates,

here is an example of filtering on exact date...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['table']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['X', 'Y1', 'Y2'],
    [new Date(2016, 7, 1), 10, 14],
    [new Date(2016, 8, 1), 14, 22],
    [new Date(2016, 9, 1), 16, 24],
    [new Date(2016, 10, 1), 22, 30],
    [new Date(2016, 11, 1), 28, 36],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 1), 30, 44],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 1), 34, 42],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 1), 36, 44],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 1), 42, 50],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 1), 48, 56]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setRows(data.getFilteredRows([
    {column: 0, value: new Date(2016, 11, 1)}
  ]));

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Table(container);
  chart.draw(view);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

*note*: if the date values include **specific time values**, then you'll need to use a range, to filter for a specific date...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['table']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['X', 'Y1', 'Y2'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 1, 12, 35, 16), 30, 44],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 1, 14, 46, 10), 34, 42],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 1, 16, 12, 44), 36, 44],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 1, 17, 20, 47), 42, 50],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 1, 18, 23, 59), 48, 56],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 2, 12, 35, 16), 30, 44],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 2, 14, 46, 10), 34, 42],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 2, 16, 12, 44), 36, 44],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 2, 17, 20, 47), 42, 50],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 2, 18, 23, 59), 48, 56]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setRows(data.getFilteredRows([{
    column: 0,
    minValue: new Date(2017, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
    maxValue: new Date(2017, 0, 1, 23, 59, 59)
  }]));

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Table(container);
  chart.draw(view);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: so if I have to filter based on the date then I have to check it by first converting it into the string and then matching it?

Comment: Also, this code snippet is giving error "view.setRows is not a function"

Comment: runs fine above, check that you have the `new` keyword when creating `view` -- as for dates, see __EDIT__ above...

Comment: `arrayToDataTable` doesn't need `new` keyword, it is a static method...