# Change data dynamically for Google Charts

Tags: google-visualization, visualization

I have data in the format of:

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Date     | Name     | Sent     | Received |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1-1-2020 | A        |        5 |        6 |
| 2-1-2020 | A        |        2 |        3 |
| 3-1-2020 | A        |        7 |        3 |
| 4-1-2020 | A        |        7 |        3 |
| 5-1-2020 | A        |        7 |        3 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+

+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Date     | Name     | Sent     | Received |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1-1-2020 | B        |        6 |        3 |
| 2-1-2020 | B        |        2 |        3 |
| 3-1-2020 | B        |        1 |        2 |
| 4-1-2020 | B        |        3 |        6 |
| 5-1-2020 | B        |        5 |        3 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+

+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Date     | Name     | Sent     | Received |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1-1-2020 | C        |        6 |        3 |
| 2-1-2020 | C        |        2 |        3 |
| 3-1-2020 | C        |        1 |        2 |
| 4-1-2020 | C        |        3 |        6 |
| 5-1-2020 | C        |        5 |        3 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I want to plot the day-wise total for Sent and Received using google charts.
I should be able to put Name as a filter to include single/multiple data sources.

I tried using state change handler on Category Filter, but after changing the data source, the new dashboard still displays the old data.
Any leads would be appreciated.

Here is the code I tried.

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="dashboard_div" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; margin-top: 1em; height: 500px">

  <p style="padding-left: 1em"><strong>Donuts eaten per person</strong></p>
        <div style="padding-left: 1em" id="categoryPicker_div"></div>
        <div id="chart_div" style="padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px; height: 400px"></div>
        <div id="time_div"></div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart', 'line', 'controls']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

  var categoryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'categoryPicker_div',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnIndex': 1,
      'ui': {
        'labelStacking': 'vertical',
        'label': 'Workgroup Selection:',
        'allowTyping': true,
        'allowMultiple': true
      }
    }
  });

  var line = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'LineChart',
    'containerId': 'chart_div',
    'options': {
      'legend': {'position': 'top'},
        'curveType': 'linear',
        'animation': {
          'startup': false,
          'duration': 0,
          'easing': 'out'
      },
      'chartArea': {'height': '80%','width': '85%'},
      'lineWidth': 3,
      'hAxis': {'title': 'Date'},
      'vAxis': {
        'viewWindow': {'min': 0 },
        'viewWindowMode':'pretty'
        },
      'crosshair':{
        'trigger': 'both'
      }
    },
    'view': {'columns': [0, 2, 3]}
  });

  var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
    'containerId': 'time_div',
    'options': {
      // Filter by the date axis.
      'filterColumnIndex': 0,
      'ui': {
        'chartType': 'LineChart',
        'chartOptions': {
          'chartArea': {'width': '85%', 'height':'20%'},
          'hAxis': {'baselineColor': 'none'}
        },
        'chartView': {'columns': [0, 2, 3]},
        // 1 day in milliseconds = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 86,400,000
        'minRangeSize': 86400000
      }
    }
    //'state': {'range': {'start': new Date(2016, 9, 1),'end': new Date(2016, 10, 1)}}
  });

var Data_ = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Workgroup', 'Sent', 'Received'],
    [new Date(2016, 9, 15), 'A', 25, 3],
    [new Date(2016, 9, 20), 'B', 31, 2],
    [new Date(2016, 9, 21), 'C', 15, 5],
    [new Date(2016, 9, 22), 'D', 7, 0],
    [new Date(2016, 9, 23), 'E', 13, 1],
    [new Date(2016, 9, 24), 'F', 8, 4],
    [new Date(2016, 9, 25), 'G', 8, 3],
    [new Date(2016, 9, 26), 'H', 13, 1],
    [new Date(2016, 9, 29), 'I', 22, 4]
  ]);

var Data_A = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Workgroup', 'Sent', 'Received'],
    [new Date(2016, 9, 19), 'A', 5, 0],
    [new Date(2016, 9, 20), 'B', 3, 2],
    [new Date(2016, 9, 21), 'C', 0, 1],
    [new Date(2016, 9, 22), 'D', 2, 0],
    [new Date(2016, 9, 24), 'F', 4, 2],
    [new Date(2016, 9, 25), 'G', 3, 1],
    [new Date(2016, 9, 26), 'H', 4, 1],
    [new Date(2016, 9, 27), 'I', 3, 2]
  ]);

  // var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  //dashboard.bind([control, categoryPicker], line);
  //dashboard.draw(Data_);

  function drawDash(Data){
      console.log("inside drawDash");
      Data = eval(Data);
      console.log(Data);
      dashboard.bind([categoryPicker, control],line)
      dashboard.draw(Data);
      };

  google.visualization.events.addListener(categoryPicker, 'statechange', function (){
    console.log("State Changed");
    console.log(categoryPicker.getState().selectedValues[0]);

    if (categoryPicker.getState().selectedValues[0] === undefined){
      console.log("Default Value Selected");
      drawDash(Data_);
    }
    else{
      drawDash("Data_"+categoryPicker.getState().selectedValues[0]);
    }

  });

drawDash(Data_);  

}

</script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: for clarification, I see where you have data tables `Data_` & `Data_A`. if category A is selected, you want to display the chart using data table `Data_A`, correct? but do you also want to only show the rows where `'A'` is in the name column of `Data_A`? and what if more than one category is selected? (A and B)

Comment: When only A is selected, I want to plot Data_A.
If A and B both are selected, I want to plot the cumulative of both the data sets.
The cumulative data will have unique date field, with the sent and received field added from the both the individual datasets.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the listener is redrawing the whole dashboard (and maybe resetting the filters). Instead, you could try redrawing only the chart by calling line.draw()

Additionally, instead of creating 2 separate DataTables, I'd create only one and filter a view according to the selected value. For example:

```
view.setRows(Data_.getFilteredRows([{
  column: 1,
  value: categoryPicker.getState().selectedValues[0]
},
```

This suggestion is detailed on this question: [I need to filter elements in google.visualization.datatable used in Google Charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43232078/i-need-to-filter-elements-in-google-visualization-datatable-used-in-google-chart#43232730)

Comment: I am not sure if the filter method satisfies my requirement.
The initial table drawn is cumulative of all the Data table, i.e. A, B and C, based on the "date" keys.
But, once I select a value from the filter, the data is changed completely.

Comment: have you tried appending one table to another and creating an additional column to differentiate them? Then you could filter this appended table based on that new column. If you want to select multiple categories and accumulate them, you could [create a grouped DataTable](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_group) based on your filters. You may create a custom function to group however you'd like.